# IE11 Height issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to assign the height of image1 to image 2. Working fine in Edge, Chrome, and Firefox. IE11 not working and there are no error messages.
This is how it looks in Edge, Chrome and Firefox: No issue:
[image: No issue]
In IE11: IE11 issue:
[image: IE11 issue]

```js
function setIntHeight() {
    var g1 = $('.grid-tile').eq(0),
        h = g1.find('img').height();
    $('.interruptor1, .interruptor2').height(h);
}

function interruptorHeight() {
    $(window).on('load', setIntHeight);
    $(window).on('resize', debounce(setIntHeight));
}

interruptorHeight();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Image 1-->
<li class="grid-tile">
<div class="product-tile" >
<div class="product-image">
<img src="https://development-na01-arden.demandware.net/dw/image/v2/BBVB_DEV/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-master-catalog/default/dwf7e4c6a8/images/large/8B-AP04151-cc521986-d8f4-4c81-b43a-787622068cba.jpg?sw=265&amp;sh=398&amp;sm=fit" alt="PLUS Blessed Tee">
</div>
</div>
</li>

<!--Image 2-->
<li class="bg-image grid-tile interruptor1">
  <img  src="https://development-na01-arden.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-ardene-Library/default/dwb58b67e0/homepage/MasonryImage5.jpg" alt="PLUS Blessed Tee" >
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(window).on('load', setIntHeight); 
Won't work in IE11 properly. Please try using:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    setIntHeight();
};
```

There are lot of explanations all over the website, research around.